# PowerDesigner Reference Lines Mess

Tags: powerdesigner

While using power designer, I have ended up with a mess of lines for references from one table to the other. While these lines are orthogonal, they create a mess, hiding behind tables, etc.

Is there a way to make them snap to grid lines so they are more readable?

Comment: Which version are you using? With version 15.0+, there is an auto-layout tool, which could help to avoid the routing by reordering the tables.

Comment: I am using version 16.5, and I have the orthogonal auto-layout, but this is not snapping the reference lines to the grid lines.

Comment: Although it is not snapping to the grid lines, playing around with auto-layout tool seems to cover my needs. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @pascal if you add what you said as an answer I will accept it as correct, since it solved my problem with the messed lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version are you using? With version 15.0+, there is an auto-layout tool, under `Symbols > Auto-Layout`, which could help to avoid the routing by reordering the tables.

I think some efforts have been made in 16.0+, around links crossings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use graphical synonms..use Ctrl + C to copy the entity. and then Ctrl + K..

It will create replica to main entity to which other entities are linking. You can put this entity with other entities on other page ( if you are using page layout) and it will avoid crossing of lines and your diagram will look beautiful.

Comment: Thanks very much !!!!!!!
It's a very efficient way to manage massive tables !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The auto-layout tool certainly helps with lines that are hidden, but it isn't perfect either. It tends to hide lines when diagrams get to big. I think the optimal way is having multiple diagrams centered around your different subjects which can already reduce the problem.

Aside from that, if you right click on a relationship, there is a Disposition option which gives you a certain flexibility to re-arrange lines, like re-ordering attach points.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Display Preferences -> ckick on your line type -> Format -> Modify -> change line corners to not orthogonal and draw them as you like)